# Modify grid-template-columns using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the size of `grid-template-columns` upon the click of a button (https://jsfiddle.net/3ft6svgk/2/).

html:

```
<div class="grid-squares">
  <div class="grid_item">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <button id="firstButton">Learn More</button>
  </div>
   <div class="grid_item">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  </div>
   <div class="grid_item">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  </div>  
   <div class="grid_item">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.grid-squares{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
}
```

javscript:

```
firstButton = document.getElementById("firstButton")
firstButton.onclick = function(){
  squaresGrid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-squares");
  squaresGrid.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1000px";
}
```

With this code I am getting

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'gridTemplateColumns' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.repairsAndUpgradesButton.onclick"
```

in the console. How can I properly change the value of `grid-template-columns`?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
firstButton = document.getElementById("firstButton")
firstButton.onclick = function(){
  squaresGrid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-squares");
  squaresGrid[0].style.gridTemplateColumns = "1000px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements.

You either need to loop over your `.gridSquares`:

```
squaresGrid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-squares");
for (let i = 0; i < squaresGrid.length; i++) {
   squaresGrid[i].style.gridTemplateColumns = "1000px";
}
```

Or access them by index (you only have one, at index `0`):

```
squaresGrid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-squares")[0];
squaresGrid.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1000px";
```

You will also want to make use of *[Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)*, and *[add an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)* to your button rather than make use of `.onclick`.

This can be seen in the following working example:

```js
firstButton = document.getElementById("firstButton")
firstButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  squaresGrid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-squares")[0];
  squaresGrid.style.gridTemplateColumns = "1000px";
});
```

```css
.grid-squares {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-squares">
  <div class="grid_item">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <button id="firstButton">Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```